# PostgreSQL accessing the same data in different timezones

Tags: postgresql, timezone, data-consistency

I'm using postgreSQL to store my data where users from different timezones can access.

However, the data is inconsistent.

For example, user A from Canada and user B from Australia can see different content of the same data if they are trying to access the data at the same moment. Is there a way to make sure the data is consistent so people from different timezones can see the same content of data at the same moment?

I've already put timestamps with time zones when creating tables

Comment: What does "the same moment" mean?

Comment: For example, user A created a project at September 20th 8am, in the meanwhile, the current time for user B when the project is created is September 20th 8pm, now user B edits the project and saved the edits to the database, then user A wants to check what user B edited, so user A re-loaded the project only to find that there's no edits at all. The reason why user A can't see user B's edits is because user A is trying to query the data at 8am, but the data is stored at 8pm.

Comment: So my point is to synchronize their edits, so whichever timezones the users are from, they should always be able to see the same content instead of different content at different time.